# Haskell: Understanding the bind and >> functions

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, io-monad

I have the following Haskell expression:

```
a = getLine >>= putStrLn . filter isDigit >> a
```

I am having trouble understanding how the above expression works. I know the `>>=` function takes a monadic value and a function (that takes a normal value and returns a monadic value), and returns a monadic value.

I know that `getLine` and `putStrLn` have the following type declarations:

```
getLine :: IO String 
putStrLn :: String -> IO ()
```

So the following part of expression:

```
a = getLine >>= putStrLn . filter isDigit
```

Would return an `IO ()`. However, the function `>>` takes a first monadic value and a second monadic value and returns the second monadic value.

Given the original expression, the first argument passed to `>>` would be of type `IO String`. The second argument is `a`.

My question is, what is the type of `a`, and how does the above expression work to continually take user input and print only the numeric part of the input back to the screen? Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: `a :: IO t`. Yes, it's polymorphic. An infinite computation never returns anything, so it can be any type.

Comment: If the definition were `a=a` (an infinite recursion), the type would be `a :: forall b. b`, i.e. `a` could be of any type `b`. Since we have instead `a = ioAction >> a`, we force `b` to be of the form `IO t`, but `t` can be anything. So we get `a :: forall t. IO t`. It is still an infinite recursion, except that the IO action is run at every recursive call. In a sense, this works since `>>` won't evaluate its second argument/action before having executed its first argument/action.

Comment: fully parenthesized, what you have is `a = (getLine >>= (putStrLn . filter isDigit)) >> a`. (both `>>` and `>>=` are `infixl 1`).

Comment: You say, "the first argument passed to `>>` would be of type `IO String`". What do you believe the first argument passed to `>>` is? Why do you believe it to have type `IO String`? (That is not the correct type for the first argument, so if you explain your thinking, we may help you spot an error in it.)

Answer (score 6):

**Note**: I renamed the `a` function to `readPrintLoop` as suggested by [@SamuelBarr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57217952/haskell-understanding-the-bind-and-functions/57218366?noredirect=1#comment100949997_57218366), since that avoids some confusion.

> My question is, what is the type of `readPrintLoop`, and how does the above expression work to continually take user input and print only the numeric part of the input back to the screen?

`readPrintLoop` has type: `readPrintLoop :: IO a` so it is an `IO`. The `a` can be any type, since we never "return" that value, we will never end this function.

The function is constantly repeated because `readPrintLoop` is defined in terms of itself. `readPrintLoop` is defined as:

```
readPrintLoop :: IO a
readPrintLoop = getLine >>= putStrLn . filter isDigit >> readPrintLoop
```

We here thus have infinite recursion, since eventually you will run into `a`, and thus replace that with another `getLine >>= putStrLn . filter isDigit >> a` and so on.

> However, the function `>>` takes a first monadic value and a second monadic value and returns the second monadic value.

`(>>)` is equivalent to:

```
(>>) :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b
u >> v = u >>= (\_ -> v)
```

so the implementation of `a` is equivalent to:

```
readPrintLoop :: IO a
readPrintLoop = getLine >>= putStrLn . filter isDigit >>= \_ -> readPrintLoop
```

Here the underscore variable `_` will be passed `()`.

Comment: It may be worth clarifying that the function named `a` and the type variable `a` are two different things. With some more sensible naming, we have `readPrintLoop :: IO a`, and `readPrintLoop = getLine >>= putStrLn . filter isDigit >> readPrintLoop`

Comment: There is an error in the definition of `>>`: `m` is not defined, and should be `u`.

Answer (score 5):

```
a  =  getLine >>= putStrLn . filter isDigit
```

is *not* "the part of expression".

```
      getLine >>= putStrLn . filter isDigit
```

is the part of the expression. And it does not "*return* `IO ()`". It *has* the type `IO ()` (which you've correctly inferred <sup>(*)</sup>). It *is* a *"monadic value"* that you talk about.

Giving it a name, [any name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57217952/haskell-understanding-the-bind-and-functions#comment100940804_57217952),

```
ioAction :: IO ()
ioAction  =  getLine >>= (putStrLn . filter isDigit)
```

we end up with

```
a  =  ioAction >> a 
----------------------------------
 (>>)     :: IO a -> IO b -> IO b
 ioAction :: IO ()
 a        ::         IO b
----------------------------------
 a        ::                 IO b
```

and everything typechecks.

The semantics of `a` in

```
a  =  ((>>) ioAction) a
```

is defined by the semantics of `>>`.

---

<sup>(*)</sup>

```
---------------------------------------------------- 
    (>>=)                     :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
    getLine                   :: IO String                   m a
    putStrLn                  ::    String -> IO ()          
    putStrLn . filter isDigit ::    String -> IO ()            a -> m b
----------------------------------------------------        ------------
 getLine >>= (putStrLn . filter isDigit)   :: IO ()          m        b
```